# Altium - Is it possible to move the symbols added to pins when creating components?

Tags: altium, inverter, symbol

I'm drawing a simple inverter and would like to have the Schmidt trigger symbol inside of it. 
Altium places it outside the boundaries. Can't find how to move & scale it. Suggestions are welcomed!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe (in Altium) it is not possible to move (or scale) a pin's *symbol type* on a schematic symbol either during creation or as an edit after creation. Sometimes, I use that *canned* function when I create schematic symbol/pins like inverted, input, output, etc but in your (Schmitt trigger) case I just create my own dumb graphic symbol (in the schematic library editor) that I can scale it to the symbol body and pin. It's not really an attribute to that pin in question but works for me; I like my schmitt graphic better anyhow:) Once done, I will then re-use that graphic over-and-over for all like schematic symbols. See attached...
[image]

Comment: I ended up doing something else... You can add standard symbols to the design using Place --> IEEE Symbols. In there is an hysteresis symbol which I've placed similar to the way you did.